# How to upload a file from Google Colab to GitHub or Kaggle?

Tags: google, github, upload

As you all know we are able to load a file from a site such as *Kaggle* and *GitHub* to *Google Collab*, we apply the bellow code to download from other sites into *Google Collab*:

```
wget nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.6B.zip
```

but I am very curious to know if I am able to upload a saved file in *Google Collab* to another site through some commands like the above? I mean I can do it manually in some multiple steps but please let me know if there are some commands to upload a file directly from *Google Collab* into another site such as *GitHub*.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I’m not entirely sure what you’re trying to achieve. Are you asking essentially how to 1) download files from Google Colab and then upload them to either 2) GitHub or 3) Kaggle? Could you please [edit] your question to clarify? Thanks.

Comment: Dear David,
I wanna to know how I can upload a file from google collab or google drive into github or kaggle by using commands. I do not want to do it manually just let me know if there are commands to uploading exactly like downloading commands which let us download datasets or files from other sites as below:
" wget nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.6B.zip"
thank you for replying

Comment: Dear David,
I am thankful for replying, tell u the truth I am not a native English speaker so I could not put my meaning in words clearly. 
I am gonna to re-write the question one time more. In fact I just asked one question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a file to a Git repository and upload it to GitHub please refer to its official help articles [Creating a new repository](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-new-repository/), [Cloning a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/#platform-linux), and [Adding a file to a repository using the command line](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-file-to-a-repository-using-the-command-line/#platform-linux). I’ll include the most important steps below:

1. Install Git:

   ```sh
   sudo apt install git
   ```
2. [Create a repository on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-new-repository/).
3. Import (or “clone”) the Git repository and enter its top directory:

   ```sh
   git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
   cd YOUR-REPOSITORY
   ```
4. Place the desired file into the repository directory (or one of its sub-directories) e. g. by moving or copying it from another place or downloading it from an external resource.
5. Add the file to the Git repository:

   ```sh
   git add my-file
   ```
6. Commit the changes to the repository:

   ```sh
   git commit --message="Add my-file"
   ```
7. Upload (or “push”) the committed changes to the upstream repository (here: at GitHub):

   ```sh
   git push
   ```

Obviously you don’t need to repeat steps 1–3 if you did them before.

Comment: Hi  @175814 , i'm looking forward to find a way to upload a file from linux terminal as google collab to kaggle. would u help me with it ?

Comment: @Maryam: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi David, regarding to the peer suggestion, I opened a new question page. please visit the page.

https://askubuntu.com/q/1090489/841701